# Выполнить функцию если у блока будет класс

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".btn-cart").click(function () {
    $(".cart").toggleClass("cart-active");
});
```

Нужно выполнить данную функцию если у блока (".cart") будет класс ("cart-active")

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(".cart").length){
       return;
   } else {
     $(".cart").toggleClass("cart-active");
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Это просто)

```
if ($(".cart").hasClass("cart-active")) {
event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: метод hasClass() не работает, потому что класс ("cart-active") добавляет jQuery. а hasClass() проверят на самом html документе есть ли класс.

Comment: вы точно проверили? так как $(".cart").hasClass("cart-active") это тоже jQuery, и привязано оно только к блоку .cart